# What are named entity advantages over strings?

Tags: named-entity-recognition

I am unclear about the practical benefit of named entity recognition. Specifically, I don't get how this entity is any better than a string representation of the same object. Let's take the popular example of movies. I can create a model where each row is a movie. Any attribute you can have in a recommendation system can just as easily be a column in my movie table: release date, actors, genre, etc. If a user does a search for 'animation' - or even if they don't, but you know from that user's history that they saw The Lion King, any decent search engine could pull up Moana as a recommendation, so how is a named entity any better?

Or you pull a named entity out of a text document. Great, but now what? Isn't it still just a string, which can be assigned as an object with it's own unique dict of values, like genre and release date? I assume there are benefits over strings, or it wouldn't be such a big deal to so many people. I just don't know what those benefits are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comparison between named entity and string is irrelevant, because the concept of named entity doesn't belong to data types such as string or numeric values. Of course a named entity is usually represented as a string but so is a text document, a cryptographic key or a translation of a text to Vietnamese: what matters here is the semantics, not the technical representation.

The reason why [named entities (NEs)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_entity) are often offered special treatment is because they are particularly relevant for certain tasks and are notoriously difficult to detect and analyze:

- The task of [Named Entity Recognition (NER)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named-entity_recognition) consists in detecting named entities in a raw text document. It's not a trivial task, the problem is still an active area of research.
- Even after having been identified, named entities are often difficult to [disambiguate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_linking). The same entity may appear under many different variants for various reasons:

  - "John Smith", "J. Smith" and "John A. Smith" may or may not be the same person.
  - "The president" and "Donald Trump" may or may not be the same entity.
  - "Big Apple" and "New York" represent the same entity, but not "big apple" and "New York".
  - ...

Of course when one is provided with the result of the NE recognition/disambiguation process, they can process NEs like any other piece of information... but that's because all the hard work about NEs has been done before.

Comment: The links you provided were very helpful, in addition to your answer itself. Thank you!